# Function inside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function mm_posts() {
  $result = '';      

  if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=4');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, array(300, 200) );

    function mega_thmb() {
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
        $img = '<img src="' .  $post_thumbnail_url[0] . '" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
      else :
        $img = '<img src="' .  get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/no-image.gif" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
      endif;

      return $img;
    }

      $result .= '
        <div class="col-md-3">' .
          mega_thmb() .
          '<div>Sport</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        </div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  endif;
  return $result;
}
```

Php displays error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mega_thmb() (previously declared in ...

What should I do? How write function inside the loop?

Comment: PHP has no concept of nested functions. What are you trying to achieve by having the definition of mega_thmb inside the definition of mm_posts?

Comment: @IMSoP, mega_thmb() must used inside the loop. Because, If I'll use mega_thmb outside the loop, it won't return me $post_thumbnail_url[0].

Comment: That's not how PHP works (you've been using JS a lot, perhaps, with its nested scopes). A function is just a global function, wherever it is defined, and had access only to the variables passed to it.

Comment: @IMSoP, thanks for help, I solved my problem! :) Used function outside the loop, and outside the mm_posts() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. Structure your code as follows. Additionally, each time the loop is run you're declaring the function again, even though it's already in memory. It needs to be outside the loop. Best practice would be to not embed the function at all

```
function mega_thmb() {
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
        $img = '<img src="' .  $post_thumbnail_url[0] . '" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
      else :
        $img = '<img src="' .  get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/no-image.gif" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
      endif;

      return $img;
    }   

function mm_posts() {
  $result = '';      

  if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=4');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, array(300, 200) );



      $result .= '
        <div class="col-md-3">' .
          mega_thmb() .
          '<div>Sport</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        </div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  endif;
  return $result;
}
```

I suggest reading the PHP documents, and consulting a few tutorials before moving any further. There are probably some other changes that need to be made to your code to make it completely correct, but please don't define functions inside of other functions, especially inside loops. Read the manual.

Comment: if I define this function outside the loop, my code will not work, because variable '$post_thumbnail_url[0]' written in mega_thmb() function must be used inside loop..

Comment: Declare that variable outside the function. Or at the very least, embed the function outside the loop, that's your main issue.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the function mm_posts runs, you are defining a function called mega_thmb. But in PHP, there can only be one function with a particular name (apart from methods in different classes), so this causes the error you are seeing.

You are trying to do this because you think it will give you access to the variable $post_thumbnail_url, but that's not how PHP works either - a function can only see the variables passed to it as parameters, or included from global scope with the `global` keyword. Anything else is a local variable whose value will start off as `null`.

There are two solutions I can see:

- Define a normal function mega_thumb (what do you have against that u?) which is passed $post_thumbnail_url as a parameter.
- Put the code that's currently in the broken mega_thmb straight into mm_posts, because you only use it in one place anyway, and it's only a couple of lines long.